# couldn't passing the data from axios to data return variable in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, this

I have an issue in my vue template down below. I fetched data from axios but it couldn't store the data on `this.sub_brand` variable. `console.log(this.sub_brand)` is only working for inside axios. here is the full code -

```
<template>
<div>
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-md-4 pt-5 pl-5">
            <div class="product">
                <div class="product__images">
                    <img
                        src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/gsm.jpg"
                        alt="google pixel 6"
                        class="product__main-image"
                        id="main-image"
                    />

                    <div class="product__slider-wrap">
                        <div class="product__slider">
                            <img
                                src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/gsm.jpg"
                                alt="google pixel 6"
                                class="product__image product__image--active"
                            />
                            <img
                                src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/gsm.jpg"
                                alt="google pixel 6"
                                class="product__image"
                            />
                            <img
                                src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/gsm.jpg"
                                alt="google pixel 6"
                                class="product__image"
                            />
                            <img
                                src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/gsm.jpg"
                                alt="google pixel 6"
                                class="product__image"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 pt-5 pr-5">
            <h4>{{sub_brand}}</h4>
            <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" id="" v-model="sub_brand"> -->
            <h5>Star</h5>
            <div class="bg-light mt-4" style="padding: 10px 0px">
                <h2 class="pl-4 pt-3">RM869.00</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-4">
                <h3>Variation</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="bg-light mt-4" style="padding: 10px 0px">
                <h5 class="pl-4">Quantity: </h5>
                <input type="number" class="form-control pl-4" placeholder="0" style="width: 12%; margin-left: 4%" min="0">
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-5">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary ml-3">Add to Cart</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary ml-3">Buy Now</button>
            </div>
            <hr class="mt-5">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bg-light">
            <div class="pl-5">
                <h3><strong>Samsung</strong></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="pl-5 custom_pan">
                <a href="">Chat</a>
                <a href="" class="pl-3">Video Chat</a>
                <a href="" class="pl-3">View</a>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="pl-5 mt-4 pr-4">
                <strong>Shipping Details</strong>
                <p style="color: #D1D3D4">2A, Changkat Duta Kiara, Mont Kiara, 50480 Kuala Lumpur, Willayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur</p>
                <strong>From: China Logistic, Shankal</strong>
                <br><br>
                <strong>To: Kuala Lumpur, Willayah Persekutuan</strong>
                <br><br>
                <strong>Shipping Fee: RM8.00</strong>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="pl-5 mt-5">
                <h5>Authentic</h5>
                <br>
                <h5>15 Days Return</h5>
                <br>
                <h5>Free Shipping</h5>
            </div>
            <br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bg-light">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4>Product Description</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                Samsung
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bg-light">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4>Review</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                Samsung
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bg-light">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4>You may also like other product from same merchant</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                Samsung
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bg-light">
        <br><br>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
    export default {
        mounted() {
                // console.log('Component mounted.');
                this.fetchProduct(); 
        },
        data() {
            return{
                single_product: [],
                sub_brand: "",
                product_id: 6,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            fetchProduct(){
                axios.get('https://admin.globalshopping-mall.site/api/single_sub_brand_detail/'+ this.product_id)
                .then(res => {
                    this.single_product = res.data.data[0];
                    this.sub_brand = res.data.data[0].GUID;
                }).catch(err => {console.log(err);});
                
            },
            
        },
        
    }

    
</script>

<style>
    .card{
        margin-top: 2%;
        margin-left: 4%;
        background-color: white;
        width: 71%;
        /* height: 30%; */
    }
    .card-header{
        background-color: white
    }

    .product {
        width: 100%;
        height: 68%;
    }

    .product__images {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .product__main-image {
        max-width: 500px;
        max-height: 600px;
        object-fit: cover;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 1px solid #070707;
    }

    .product__slider-wrap {
        max-width: 500px;
        min-height: 100px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .product__slider {
        width: 98%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        overflow-x: auto;
        padding-left: 2%;
    }

    .product__image {
        max-width: 180px;
        max-height: 100px;
        object-fit: cover;
        cursor: pointer;
        opacity: 0.5;
        margin: 0.25rem;
        border: 1px solid #070707;
    }

    .product__image:first-child {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    .product__image:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    .product__image:hover {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .product__image--active {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .product__slider::-webkit-scrollbar {
        height: 10px;
    
    }

    .product__slider::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: #D1AD33;
        border-radius: 50px;
    
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look, the problem is, your context `this.` works inside axios with context of axios 
If you want to use context `this.` of vue component, you have to get data from axios outside. 
You have to use async/await for you vue method fetchProduct 
Something like that

```
methods: {
    async fetchProduct() {
      let result = await axios.get("https://admin.globalshopping-mall.site/api/single_sub_brand_detail/" +this.product_id)
        .then((res) => {
          return res.data.data[0];
        })
        .catch((err) => {console.log(err);});

      this.single_product = result;
      this.sub_brand = result.GUID;
    },
  },
```

or
You can save your context `this` to the variable before axios
and use this variable inside the axios function 
Something like this

```
methods: {
    fetchProduct() {
      let _this = this;
      axios.get("https://admin.globalshopping-mall.site/api/single_sub_brand_detail/" + this.product_id)
        .then((res) => {
          _this.single_product = res.data.data[0];
          _this.sub_brand = res.data.data[0].GUID;
        })
        .catch((err) => {console.log(err);});
      console.log(this);
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

***Root cause :*** As axios API calls works asynchronously, But other code will execute synchronously. Hence, While trying to logging `this.sub_brand` it will work synchronously and will invoke before the axios call (response time might vary).

***Solution :*** If you want to access the API response immediately after a call. You have to use `async`/`await` which make promises easier to write.

- `async` makes a function return a Promise
- `await` makes a function wait for a Promise

Live Demo **:**

```
methods: {
    async fetchProduct(){
        const res = await axios.get('https://admin.globalshopping-mall.site/api/single_sub_brand_detail/'+ this.product_id)
        .then(res => {
          return res.data.data[0];
        }).catch(err => {console.log(err);});            
    }
    this.single_product = res;
    this.sub_brand = res.GUID;         
}
```